# How to convert string to datetime format if it is in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to plot a graph with dates format. The thing is that I have problem with the format of the dates column.

I have tried to use the solution like this:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

It works. But the problem is that when I append the value of the `Date` in the dataframe into a list, the format of my `Date` column turns back to `String`. How do I solve this case?

Comment: `when I append the value of the Date in the dataframe into a list, the format of my Date column turns back to String.` - Are you sure? Because if value is converted to datetime then appending not change types. Can you add your full code?

Comment: can you write down the output format that you need? Give the current state of the data frame and the desired state of data frame. It would be helpful to solve the case.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work

solution1

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Solution2

date is the list of date in string formate,if u want to convert into datetime then try this code

```
dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%Y-%m-%d"').date() for date in dates]
```